# What's the difference between a Page and a Slide in Google Slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

The API for Google Slides has two classes:

- [Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide)
- [Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page)

The documentation merely states "An *X* in a presentation" (where *X* is the class in question).

What's the difference conceptually? Is a page something you get when you are printing the presentation?

I see an "New Slide" function in the menu, but how does one use Pages in Google Slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-type) suggests that a Page can be a

- Slide,
- Layout or
- Master

And the description of the methods listed for [Layout](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/layout) seem to support this idea.

But I have not seen any documentation say this specifically.